# How to avoid tokenize words with underscore?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize my texts by using "`nltk.word_tokenize()`" function, but it would split words connected by "`_`".

For example, the text "`A,_B_C! is a movie!`" would be split into:

```
['a', ',', '_b_c', '!', 'is','a','movie','!']
```

The result I want is:

```
['a,_b_c!', 'is', 'a', 'movie', '!']
```

My code:

```py
import nltk

text = "A,_B_C! is a movie!"
nltk.tokenize(text.lower())
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The trouble is that you're using `word_tokenize`, and commas separate words. I've never used `nltk`, but I have written a lexer before using [rply](https://rply.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide/lexers.html). It might be helpful here.

Comment: text.split() will give you the result

Comment: @Asif but the split would give "movie!" as a whole

Comment: you can use regex to identify the pattern for ex - `",_" ` and replace `,` with `_,_` and apply the tokenizer.  once the tokenization is done and you replace the `_,_ ` with `,_`

Comment: I think you will need to write a custome regex to deal with this, since the way you are treating spaces, commas, underscores, and punctuation take this out of the scope of any standard parsing I can think of.  There is nltk.tokenize.regexp for doing this: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=nltk.tokenize.regexp

Comment: sorry for that. In that case if split is to be used then space have to added before every punctuation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first split it using space and then use `word_tokenize` on each word to handle punctuations

```
[word for sublist in [word_tokenize(x) if '_' not in x else [x] 
                       for x in text.lower().split()] for word in sublist]
```

Output
`['a,_b_c!', 'is', 'a', 'movie', '!']`

`l = [word_tokenize(x) if '_' not in x else [x]  for x in text.lower().split()]` will return a list of list running `word_tokenize` only on words which dont have `_`.

`[word for sublist in l for word in sublist]` part is to flatten the list of list into a single list.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to TweetTokenizer rather than word_tokenize if you want to keep underscores and not separate around underscores. You can find more information here: [How nltk.TweetTokenizer different from nltk.word_tokenize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919670/how-nltk-tweettokenizer-different-from-nltk-word-tokenize)
Not sure how to solve the exclamation point issue. If you want ['a,_b_c!'] you'll also be getting ['movie!'] and if you want ['movie','!'] you'll also be getting ['a,_b_c','!']. I can't think of a way to pick and choose how exclamation points are handled.