# How nltk.TweetTokenizer different from nltk.word_tokenize?

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, tokenize

I am unable to understand the difference between the two. Though, I come to know that word_tokenize uses Penn-Treebank for tokenization purposes. But nothing on TweetTokenizer is available. For which sort of data should I be using TweetTokenizer over word_tokenize?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, both tokenizers almost work the same way, to split a given sentence into words. But you can think of `TweetTokenizer` as a subset of `word_tokenize`. `TweetTokenizer` keeps hashtags intact while `word_tokenize` doesn't.

I hope the below example will clear all your doubts...

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
from nltk.tokenize import  word_tokenize
tt = TweetTokenizer()
tweet = "This is a cooool #dummysmiley: :-) :-P <3 and some arrows < > -> <-- @remy: This is waaaaayyyy too much for you!!!!!!"
print(tt.tokenize(tweet))
print(word_tokenize(tweet))

# output
# ['This', 'is', 'a', 'cooool', '#dummysmiley', ':', ':-)', ':-P', '<3', 'and', 'some', 'arrows', '<', '>', '->', '<--', '@remy', ':', 'This', 'is', 'waaaaayyyy', 'too', 'much', 'for', 'you', '!', '!', '!']
# ['This', 'is', 'a', 'cooool', '#', 'dummysmiley', ':', ':', '-', ')', ':', '-P', '<', '3', 'and', 'some', 'arrows', '<', '>', '-', '>', '<', '--', '@', 'remy', ':', 'This', 'is', 'waaaaayyyy', 'too', 'much', 'for', 'you', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!']
```

You can see that `word_tokenize` has split `#dummysmiley` as `'#'` and `'dummysmiley'`, while TweetTokenizer didn't, as `'#dummysmiley'`.  `TweetTokenizer` is built mainly for analyzing tweets.
You can learn more about tokenizer from this [link](https://chendianblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/different-types-of-tokenizers-in-nltk/)

Comment: In addition to this answer, aonther great tutorial on `TweetTokenizer` can also be found [here](https://berkeley-stat159-f17.github.io/stat159-f17/lectures/11-strings/11-nltk..html#First-pass) and focuses on problems with tokenizing social media data.

Answer (score 1):

It also seems to deal differently with abbreviated negations ("isn't" for example):

```
from nltk.tokenize import (TweetTokenizer,
                           wordpunct_tokenize,)

text = "The quick brown fox isn't jumping over the lazy dog, co-founder 
multi-word expression. #yes!"

standard_nltk = word_tokenize(text)
print(standard_nltk)
# output: ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'is', "n't", 'jumping', 'over', 
# 'the', 'lazy', 'dog', ',', 'co-founder', 'multi-word', 'expression', '.', 
# '#', 'yes', '!']

twitter_nltk = tweet_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
print(twitter_nltk)
# output: ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', "isn't", 'jumping', 'over', 
# 'the', 'lazy', 'dog', ',', 'co-founder', 'multi-word', 'expression', '.', 
# '#yes', '!']
```